# what is gradle's equivalent of npm search?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm working on an ionic application and will need to import a particular capacitor plugin.  The plugin is in the process of moving from an individual repository to one associated with the capacitor community.
According to the docs, that plugin will currently be imported with this line in `MainActivity.java`

`import ca.zyra.capacitor.stripe.Stripe;`

But there is a github issue indicating that at some point in the near future, the package name will change to `com.getcapacitor.community.Stripe`

It would be handy to be able to do the equivalent of `npm search ca.zyra.capacitor.stripe.Stripe` from my terminal to see with if the package is still available under the original name or with the new name.  For those doing android development, is there the equivalent of the `npm search` utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is no command line equivalent.

You import it, and gradle finds it in the configured maven repositories or it does not.

So normally Android projects are configured by default to have Google's Maven repo and Jcenter maven repo but you can also add others.

You can explore and search on the web these repo's

e.g.

Google - https://maven.google.com/web/index.html

JCenter - https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter

or

https://mvnrepository.com/ has indexes for 1288 repos

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor plugins are distributed through npm, and the npm package will not change, you’ll just have to change the code in the `MainActivity.java`

Answer (score 0):

Use **mvn**:

```
mvn -q com.jarcasting:search-maven-plugin:search -Dq="com.google.guava:guava"
```

Source: https://jarcasting.com/artifacts/com.jarcasting/search-maven-plugin/